# Issue in Dash app when loading pickled model: Can't get attribute 'tokenize' on <module '__main__' from

Tags: python, pickle

I've trained a classifier in **train_classifier.py** using the following pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
    ])
```

**tokenize** is a function that is defined in this file.

I save the model using

```
with open(model_filepath, 'wb') as file:
     pickle.dump(model, file)
```

All good until there. The issue arises when I try to load the trained model in my Dash app (**app.py**, displaying page **add_new.py**) to classify new items.

**app.py**

```
[...]
@callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              Input('url', 'pathname'))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/add_new':
        return add_new.layout
[...]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**add_new.py**

```
[...]
with open(model_filepath, 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
[...]
```

When I run app.py get the following error for the line model = pickle.load(f) in add_new.py: **Can't get attribute 'tokenize' on <module '**main**' from C:/... /app.py>**

I've read through similar questions here and tried different solutions (importing tokenize function; inserting def tokenize in app.py and / or add_new.py), but nothing worked for me so far. My guess is that it has to do with the way the Dash app is setup (folder structure?). Or I made another mistake?
Here is the structure of the relevant files:

```
Dashboard
models
    __init__.py
    model.pkl
    train_classifier.py
pages
    __init__.py
    add_new.py
app.py
```

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Ok, so I think I solved it. Just had to switch the order of the imports in app.py. Just for reference / others that stumble upon the same issue: The pickle loads correctly in add_new.py if I do the following import order in app.py:
`from models.train_classifier import tokenize
from pages import add_new`